# bootstrap form-groups in input

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need your help with bootstrap form-group`s.

this is my html

```
<form action="#" class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group no-margin">
        <input type="text" class="form-control no-margin" placeholder="Search..." />
        <select class="form-control selectcity no-margin" id="sel1">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
        </select>
        <div class="input-group date no-margin" id="datetimepicker1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-3" placeholder="თარიღი" style="padding: 0 5px;" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-blue" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

it looks like they are inline
but they have margin from each other.
I tryed margin:0 in css but it not working
please help me.

this image shows how it looks now

[Image 1](http://f-picture.net/lfp/s015.radikal.ru/i330/1503/27/f666e12abbf2.png/htm)

and on this image is how I need to be

[Image 2](http://f-picture.net/lfp/s020.radikal.ru/i707/1503/91/103697654224.png/htm)

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default behavior of inline/inline-block elements: they respect whitespaces between them, including newlines, tabs, etc. The simplest fix in your case is to set `font-size: 0` to `.form-group` container, so that whitespaces are effectively rendered as zero-width:

```css
.form-group.no-margin {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

This is trick won't affect inner input elements, as for they have more specific `font-size` settings, but gaps between will disappear.

Comment: I see it working with your HTML as I described. Check the demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/BzcVyCEP15DwMmCMVBFb?p=preview Maybe you have some CSS?

Comment: no it works but...
please look at this image
http://i077.radikal.ru/1503/66/05e14defc7cd.png
and I nned that the select box and calendar box to be as input-addon
or I can tell like this
I need that the search input box must be under ths 2 box`s

as I said in the title I need that the elements be in textbox
not near.
as it is on the image